# Pass C++ enum into Objective-C constructor to set properties

Tags: c++, objective-c

Take the following C++ enum, which is generated as the result of an algorithm run from an external library. I'm then taking the resulting enum and passing it into the constructor of an Objective-C class where the enum result will determine the property values of the new object.

```
enum vehicle_t {
    car,
    truck,
    train,
    plane
};
```

Here's an abstraction of the constructor from the Objective-C class:

```
- (id)initWithVehicle:(vehicle_t)vehicle
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        switch (vehicle) {
            case 0:
                _weight = @"";
                _size = @"";
                _style = @"";
                _speed = @"";
                _origin = @"";
                break;
            case 1:
                _weight = @"";
                _size = @"";
                _style = @"";
                _speed = @"";
                _origin = @"";
                break;

            ...

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Though it works fine, I can't help but feel that it's a bit clunky and unrefined. I'm sure there's something that I'm just not thinking of. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish what I'm looking for? Thanks!

Comment: Looks OK to me, apart from using `case car:` etc. instead of `case 0:` etc.  There is nothing inelegant about this code; it's straightforward, easy to maintain and will work just fine.

Comment: I think this post belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: But it appears that Code Review isn't one of SO's 5 migration paths. Someone should look into that.

Comment: Cool, thanks @trojanfoe—and thanks @anthropomorphic, I didn't even know about Code Review!